# Setting environment variable with special characters through conda in powershell

Tags: powershell, conda, miniconda

How do you set an environment variable through conda in powershell when the value has special characters?
For example, if I run

```
conda env config vars set AZURE_CON_STRING="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=anaccount;AccountKey=7mAi16vv4iyJtp8wPLxGf0ynaergfaergergeargaerg+pmWfKfTcoom/j6Ki7aviFS/f4RSyN3gergeru1aEiw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
```

The resulting environment variable is just `core.windows.net` instead of the full string.

Using single quotes gives the same result.
I have also tried enclosing with backtick (`) and @" "@ but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash.

```
conda env config vars set AZURE_CON_STRING=\"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=anaccount;AccountKey=7mAi16vv4iyJtp8wPLxGf0ynaergfaergergeargaerg+pmWfKfTcoom/j6Ki7aviFS/f4RSyN3gergeru1aEiw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net\"
```

Hmm not sure how to get there:

```
.\echoargs foo=\"foo bar\"

Arg 0 is <foo=\foo bar">
```

Comment: Does this not have an appropriate duplicate to propose? Seems like such a basic problem task, i.e., not specific to Conda.